# R: Why is a free variable within a function recognized as an unquoted column name?

Tags: r, dplyr, scope, symbols, evaluation

My understanding is that R's scoping will always try to assign values to free variables within a function by searching the environment within which the function is defined and then searching parent environments. However, I am seeking assistance reconciling this with why I **don't** receive an error from a function call.

Suppose I define a function `foo` in the global environment and pass it arguments that are either objects (e.g., a `data.frame`) in the global environment or the unquoted names of elements of that object.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Example input objects
dv <- "c"
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(3,NA_real_), 5),
                 y = letters[1:10],
                 z = 1:10)

# Define a function
foo <- function(df, dv, response, treat) {
  df %>%
    filter(y %in% dv) %>%
    filter(!is.na(response)) %>%
    select(treat)
}
```

My understanding is that `y` is a free variable here and I should expect R will look for `y` in the global environment where `foo` was defined, find nothing, and throw an error. However, any errors/warnings are unrelated to `y`:

```r
foo(df = df, dv = dv, response = x, treat = z)
#> Error in `filter()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `..1 = !is.na(response)`.
#> Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_filter()`:
#> ! object 'x' not found
```

While we can fix those scoping errors by quoting and unquoting (per below), it remains unclear to me how `y` is recognized as an unquoted column name and not producing an error.

```r
foo_new <- function(df, dv, response, treat) {
  response <- enquo(response)
  treat <- enquo(treat)
  
  df %>%
    filter(y %in% dv) %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!response)) %>%
    select(!!treat)
}

foo_new(df, dv, x, z)
#>   z
#> 1 3
```

Comment: The variable `y`  will evaluate within your `df` data.frame using Non-Standard-Evaluation mechanism , the problem will be in `x` which will be searched in the global environment .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to make things more explicit, in regards to quoted vs. unquoted expressions and the environments from where objects are coming. If I were to roll up `foo` into an R package, this is what I'd do (using `roxygen2` comments to make the type of function arguments explicit).

```r
#' Test function
#' 
#' @param df A `data.frame`.
#' @param dv A `character` scalar.
#' @param response An unquoted expression corresponding to a column in `df`.
#' @param treat An unquoted expression corresponding to a column in `df`.
#' 
#' @importFrom magrittr "%>%"
#' @importFrom rlang .data 
foo_explicit <- function(df, dv, response, treat) {
    df %>%
        filter(.data$y %in% dv) %>%
        filter(!is.na({{ response }})) %>%
        select({{ treat }})
}
```

A few comments:

- `.data$y` inside `filter` makes it explicit that `y` is a column within `df`.
- The `dv` argument is a `character` scalar within the `foo_explicit` environment.
- The `response` and `treat` arguments are unquoted expressions. The [curly-curly operator](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/) is just a short-cut to the `enquo` + `!!` construct that you use in `foo_new`.

Comment: Hm, I thought I read somewhere that {{}} only works with `select()` and not `filter()`?

Comment: @socialscientist No that’s not correct.

Comment: @socialscientist Was on mobile device before so not easy to include a link. Here is a relevant reference on [data masking](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_data_masking.html). You might have been right at some point though; `dplyr` changed quite a bit on its way to version 1.0.x.